# light-time correction in GNSS service

Tags: visible-light, gps

I have tried to use C/A code for single point positioning with light-time correction.
I found the below equation for that.Can any one explain how to use this equation for light-time correction?

> $$\rho^{s}_{r}(t_{r},t_{s})=\rho^{s}_{r}(t_{r})+\left[\frac{d\rho^{s}_{r}(t_{r})}{dt}\right]\Delta{t}$$

**Edit 1 :** In this equation term $$\left[\frac{d\rho^{s}_{r}(t_{r})}{dt}\right]$$ is geometric distance from the satellite to the receiver derivative with respect to time

**Edit 2 :**
$$t_{s}$$ :epoch wave propagation from satellites
$$t_{r}$$ :epoch received wave in reciver
 $$\rho^{s}_{r}(t_{r},t_{s})$$ : geometric distance between satellite and station in epoch t(s)
 $$\rho^{s}_{r}(t_{r})$$ : geometric distance between satellite and station in epoch t(r)
$$\Delta{t}$$ :wave travel time (~ 0.07second)

Comment: Please define the quantities.

Comment: @flippiefanus check edit2